# Extracting values of a key from an array of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I want to read from a .npy file to do some signal processing tasks but during this task I received this error:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


file  = '/signal/data.npy'
d = np.load(file,allow_pickle=True,encoding = 'latin1')

d['soma'][0]
```

There are same questions but I could not use them to solve this one.So can anyone help me to fix It?
Thanks

This the error:
[image]

This is part of my data( d is equal to res):

[image]

Comment: Please include your `data.npy` so it is reproducible. Thank you.

Comment: I will put a sample of data, I could not upload it.

Comment: So your array includes bunch of dictionaries. Are you looking to extract ALL elements that include keys `["results"]["lfp"]` for example, or a specific element with that key?

Comment: Yes I want to pick all with those keys.

Comment: `res` is a object dtype array containing dictionaries.  `res[0]` is one of those dictionaries.  `res[0]['soma']` should work.  The indexing order matters.

Comment: @ hpaulj  yes you're right, it works. you can post it as a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data consists of arrays of dictionaries. for each array you have some keys with its values.
the solution as @ hpaulj said is:

```
   res[array_index]["your_key"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a numpy array `d` and you are trying to access e.g. `"soma"` index which is not possible. Numpy indexing rule is:
 ***only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices***.

If your numpy array includes dictionaries, you need to extract dictionaries. `d['soma']` does not extract elements of numpy array.
This loops over array `d` and extracts the first element of values of key `'soma'` for all dictionaries in `d` that has key `'soma'`:

```
lfp = [i['soma'][0] for i in d if 'soma' in i]
```

And if it is a dataframe instead of numpy array, try:

```
d = pd.read_pickle(file)
```

Comment: @Mhasa87 Edited the post. Your picture does not include an example that has key `results`. So I assume its value is also a dictionary that necessarily includes key `"lfp"`. You can include another if statement if you need to check the existence of key in the nested dictionary as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I think I have some problems, I will change this post.